# Vertically Align a Button in a Header

Tags: html, css

I know this should be fairly simple, but I for the life of me can't figure out the proper CSS to do this.

**HTML**

```
<h1>A Cool Header <button>Click Me</button></h1>
```

**CSS**

```
button{position:relative; top:50%;}
```

My attempt can be found **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/q27bk0rc/3/)**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q27bk0rc/2/

Comment: @alexforrence I've updated the original post to include both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `vertical-align: middle;` for `button`

remove `position:relative; top:50%;`

```css
h1 {background-color:green}

button{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>A Cool Header <button>Click Me</button></h1>
```

Comment: I knew there was a simple answer. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

use "**vertical-align: middle**"

```
button{  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flex box

`header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-self: center;
}`

see it running on my site's header
http://kezzi.co